# Making sense of the delete review queue

Tags: support, review, vote-to-delete

I am having trouble interpreting the information in the 10K delete review queue.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

The [help center entry](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) doesn't really go into detail about the UI. In particular, it is missing the following things, which I am wondering about:

- The meaning of the number to the left of the post.
- The meaning of the number in parentheses to the right of the post (note: it's explained [in the tool tips](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243505/230261)).
- The color (dark blue, light blue, <strike>gray</strike>) of the post.

I have been told that **X title (Y)** means that a post has **X** delete votes and **Y** more are needed to actually delete it. The **Y** part seems right, but I just voted to delete a "3 title (1)" question, and on the question itself it said there were 9 delete votes, not 3. What does the **X** mean?

The colors, I think I've been able to deduce (also, I have tested and confirmed that dark vs. light blue is not related to the visited link status in the browser, although the gray ones are visited light blue ones, which I did not realize when I first posted this):

- Dark blue = closed.
- Light blue = on hold (or [not able to be voted on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243498/making-sense-of-the-delete-review-queue#comment795902_243498)?)
- <strike>Gray = unsure: either "open", or an answer (or [not able to be voted on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243498/making-sense-of-the-delete-review-queue#comment795902_243498) - although I just spotted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26885479/i-want-to-show-restaurant-open-for-specific-times) light blue question that I am not able to cast a delete vote on yet because it is too recent).</strike>

Is that correct?

Also, I am unclear on what it means for an answer to be in that queue. I just clicked a "1 title (2)" answer. It had a score of 0. But... I can't cast delete votes on answers. This seems to be a [20K privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) (which I do not have right now). However, that privilege only allows one to vote to delete answers that have a score of -1 or lower. All the answers I saw had a score of 0, which even a 20K user could not vote to delete. So, I am unsure what type of action is merited on an answer that appears in this queue. What is the UI asking me to do with answers?

**TL;DR**

1. What does X <strike>and Y</strike> in "X Title (Y)" mean and, if X is the number of votes cast, why does it not agree with the vote count present on the question page?
2. What do the colors mean?
3. What do I do with answers?
4. Bonus: Can the help center be updated with a description of the UI? (I may post this as a separate feature request).

Comment: Also; the help center calls the 10K tools "moderation tools", but the description for [tag:moderation-tools] is "tools for diamond moderators", which I am not. So I wasn't sure if that tag was appropriate. Is it?

Comment: Grey color = you can't vote to delete this post. Dark vs light maybe just visited vs non-visited links in your browser.

Comment: @Rafflesiaarnoldii Gray: Thanks. Dark vs. light: I've just tested and confirmed it's *not* the browser link status.

Comment: @Rafflesiaarnoldii Hm; I do not think "gray" means "can not vote". [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26885479/i-want-to-show-restaurant-open-for-specific-times) is light blue for me but I cannot vote to delete it at this time (it is too recent I think -- I can't even see the delete vote count on it).

Comment: Then I suppose that light blue = cannot vote. And grey is a mystery.

Comment: @Rafflesiaarnoldii Wait, no; *gray* is a visited *light blue* link in my browser. Grrr this is maddening.

Comment: @gnat (off-topic) Why <kbd> and not e.g. quote ('>'), or nothing?

Comment: @JasonC [blame Will, he taught me the trick with kbd](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270195/839601) "Works on mobile, too..."

Comment: @gnat Oh man. I asked because the uneven margins were making me uneasy... *reflects*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My interpretation is the following. Some of this is from the tooltips that are shown when hovering over the numbers/links, other parts are derived from experimentation.

- The number on left is the number of delete votes the post already has. I noticed a few examples where there was a slight discrepancy between this number and the number of already cast delete votes shown in the post itself. Could be caching. Most of the time, the numbers are the same.
- The number in parentheses on the right is the number of delete votes still needed to delete the post.
- High intensity/brightness colors are the posts you can vote on.
- Low intensity/brightness colors are the ones you can't vote on (*).
- For both high and low intensity colors, the links with a more purely blue hue are the posts you have not visited yet, the more grayish links are for visited posts.

(*) The rules for being allowed to cast delete votes, copied from the 10K privileges page:

> You must wait for a question to be closed for 2 days before you can vote for deletion. This restriction is removed for trusted users when a post scores -3 or lower.

where "trusted user" refers to users who have reached the 20K rep privilege level.

Comment: Thanks!! Everything I see confirms what you say. I didn't notice the tool tips over the numbers in parentheses (oops). For answers, I guess the rules are similar, although they are detailed in the trusted user privilege page (the 10K privileges page talks about questions but leaves out answers).